# What would be an example of a series s.t. $a_n < \displaystyle\sum_{c=1}^{n-1}a_c$ and $a_i + a_j < a_k$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What would be an example of a geometric series s.t. $a_n < \displaystyle\sum_{c=1}^{n-1}a_c$ and $a_i + a_j < a_k$ for $i,j,k= 1,2,\ldots,n-1$

$$\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} a_c = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n-1}$$

An example of $a_i + a_j < a_k$ could be $a_4 + a_2 < a_{10}$

Comment: Your second summation states $\displaystyle\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} a_c = a_1 + a_n + \cdots + a_{n-1}$.  Did you mean $\displaystyle\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} a_c = a_1 + {\color{red}{a_2}} + \cdots + a_{n-1}$?  Also, I think that you may want to add a condition on $i$ and $j$.  For instance, I think you may be suggesting that $i < k$ and $j < k$.

Comment: Oops sorry about the typo. I fixed it. And the condition you wrote does hold true. Thanks.

Comment: So you mean $\forall (i,j,k)$ st $i,j, < k$, $a_i+a_j < a_k < a_1 + ... + a_{k-1}$ ? Given that such an $(a_n)$ has to be strictly increasing ($a_i < a_i + a_j < a_k$), this is equivalent to $a_{n-2}+a_{n-1} < a_n < a_1 + ... + a_{n-1}$

Comment: Your question must still be missing information.  $$(\forall i, j, k) a_i + a_j < a_k$$ is only possible if $a$ has an upper bound, which geometric sequences don't have.

Comment: I think it's $i,j < k$ as per the above comments

Comment: @NickFreeman: please don't forget to "Accept" the best answer to be a good M.SE citizen.

Answer (score 0):

Given that such an $(a_n)$ has to be strictly increasing (since $i < k $ and $a_j > 0$ imply $a_i < a_i + a_j < a_k$), this is equivalent to $a_{n-2}+a_{n-1} < a_n < a_1 + ... + a_{n-1}$.

If you try the form $a_n=\alpha^{n-1}$ and inject it in the inequalities above, you get:

- $\alpha^2-\alpha-1 > 0$
- $\alpha^{n-1}(2-\alpha) - 1 > 0$, in particular $\alpha^3(2-\alpha)-1 > 0$

Wolfram Alpha will give you the exact roots, but numerically $\alpha \in ]1.62, 1.83[$.

You can verify that $a_n = 1.7^{n-1}$ works ([here on W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B1.7%5E%7Bn-2%7D%2B1.7%5E%7Bn-1%7D+%2C+1.7%5En+%2C+%281.7%5En-1%29%2F0.7+%7D+for+n+%3D3+...20))

*Minor edit*

Obviously, the root of the first equation in $\alpha$ is $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.618$.

In the second equation which gives the max value for $\alpha$, you can choose different values of $n$ ($n=3$ gives you $\varphi$ again, $n=4$ gives you $\approx 1.83$, ..., as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\alpha^{(n)} \rightarrow 2$) which will be the minimum $n$ index from which the second inequality in $a_n$ is verified.

Comment: What would the geometric look like then if I wrote it out?

Comment: What do you mean by "the geometric" ?

Comment: sorry. typo. What would the geometric series look like expanded.

Comment: actually $a_n = \alpha^{n-1}$ is really the most "expanded" form possible, what more would you want ?

Comment: The series looks like $\displaystyle\sum_{c=1}^{n-1} = a_{1} + a_{2} + ... + a_{n-1}$ and so from your formulation what would I say for $a_{1} + ... +a_{n-1}$? Like what is each term then?

Comment: You mean $1 + \alpha +$ ... $+ \alpha^{n-1} = \frac{\alpha^n-1}{\alpha-1}$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18589/discussion-between-nick-freeman-and-alex-h).